# Stop div overlapping another from size increase

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

My engagement-filtercontainer div used to sit directly above my engagement-graphcontainer unless it was expanded via button click, in which case it drops down into the graphcontainer overlapping. Now the engagement-filtercontainer has grown in size because of additional content and it overlaps my graph container which contained my svg. I need it to dynamically not do this even if my filter increases in size.

I have some divs that are contained in this order:

```
<div class="Engagement-Container">
<div class="Engagement-Body">

<div class="Engagement-Graph" id="graph">
  <div class="Engagement-FilterContainer" 
   </div>
   <div class="Engagement-GraphContainer" 
   <svg
      class="Engagement-GraphSVG"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      version="1.1 ">
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Notice that the engagement-filtercontainer and graphcontainer are both within the engagement-graph div, and that my svg is contained within the graphcontainer.

In the below image you can see that the filter now with more content expands into the area (I have hidden with css thats why im showing it in dev mode, ive tried various methods to work around this but I think i need a definitive solution.

[image]

The CSS:

engagement-graph(parent div)

```
.Engagement-Graph {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
overflow: hidden;

@include tablet() {
  width: 65%;
}
}
```

Engagement-graph-container (contains the svg graph that i want to protect from unwanted overlap)

```
  .Engagement-GraphContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 56px);
  top: 0;
  background-color: $gray-bg-color;
  transition: height $filter-slide-duration, top $filter-slide-duration;

  @include tablet() {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
  }

  svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  &--WithFilter {
    height: calc(100% - 480px) !important;
    top: 480px !important;

    @include landscape {
      height: calc(100% - 436px) !important;
      top: 436px !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Filter-container (that is overlapping)

```
.Engagement-FilterContainer {
  overflow: overlay;
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: transform $filter-slide-duration;
  transform: translateY(-486px);
  visibility: hidden;
  &--Visible {
    transform: translateY(0) !important;
  }

  @include landscape {
    transform: translateY(-436px);
  }
}
```

I wish for the filter to work as usual so when its expanded it will appear into the screen but when it is not, I don't want it encroaching upon the graph, no matter how large it gets. When the filter was smaller it was fine it never came into the screen, so it must not be dynamic in how it is sized.

Thank you if you can help.

Comment: Give the div a position, for example `.Engagement-Breadcrumbs{ top: 0; }` were it is 0 pixels away from top. Then it would probably stop moving.

Comment: it does stop it from moving, but when the webpage is re-sized the div basically disappears because it moves in relation to the parent container

Comment: I don't know how your other code looks like, but if `.Engagement-FilterContainer {..}` is its parent maybe you can try giving it `position: relative;` instead of absolute. (Might not work tho).